# Tomcat not applying filter after redirection (forwarding?)

Tags: java, tomcat

Using Tomcat 7. The relevant `web.xml` parts look like this:

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>my.company.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

The code of `Filter` looks like this (simplified):

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
  System.out.println("Filter start");
  chain.doFilter(request, response);
  System.out.println("Filter finish");
}
```

The 404.jsp looks like this (very simplified):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
  System.out.println("404 here");
%>
```

The stdout output of opening a non-existent page (like `/foobar`) is this:

```
Filter start
Filter finish
404 here
```

So, in other words, while Tomcat is figuring out that the non-existent page does not exist the `Filter` runs correctly. But immediately afterwards while rendering the 404 page it is not wrapped in the `Filter`. The 404 page is otherwise rendered well, and the `Filter` is correctly applied to all the other (non-forwarded) JSPs.

If I access the 404.jsp directly, the `Filter` is correctly applied. It's only the cases where I access some missing JSP that the `Filter` is first called (see the log above) and only then 404.jsp is evaluated - but without being wrapped in `Filter`.

What can I do to have the filter wrap the 404.jsp as well?

Comment: in your Filter code, you need to return the status of 404 so that the container will call your 404.jsp

Comment: Yes, but you needed to request something that is not found. In this particular case, your mapping to /* which mean everything is intercepted by the Filter. Currently, your filter returns 200 which is why your 404.jsp is not triggered.

Comment: Ops, I misunderstood your question...so your saying Tomcat executed 404.jsp? So what is the issue?

Comment: Ok got you now. Your Filter is listening to `/*` so what would be the URL which cause 404? I would say everything match. The only way the container to forward to 404.jsp would be for you in the Filter.doFilter() to set a status of 404.

Comment: Well, anything, like `/foobar`. The `Filter` is correctly started for this non-existing resource, calling eg. `((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString()` will give me the `/foobar`, `Filter start` will get correctly logged. Then, in `chain.doFilter(request, response);` Tomcat will figure out "oh /foobar does not exist", `Filter finish` will get logged, then Tomcat will forward to the 404 page, which is my 404.jsp. But it will not run the `Filter` again :)

Comment: For a start "/foobar" exist because your Filter is mapped to `/*`. Also if it go back to the Filter again for the 404 then it would be wrong becaus it will keep looping forever!? I am not sure why the container think `/foobar` doesn't exist? The fact that it gives the handle to the your Filter suggests that it found the mapping. Maybe something else triggered 404? Oh I sees it now...your 404.jsp set the status 404 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read section 6.2.5 of the servlet specification.

You mapping is equivalent to

```xml
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

You want at least:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

So the filter mapping applies to error pages as well as normal requests.

Other dispatcher settings are available.

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was missing. Works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

The 404.jsp has the `response.setStatus(404);`. This page is called by the container to handle 404 status so no need to set it again.

Comment: Good point, thanks. The idea of that `response.setStatus(404);` is that simply directly visiting the 404.jsp page should return HTTP 404. It makes no difference in my problem however, so I am now removing this from the question.

Comment: Can you test it again now that `setStatus(404)` has been removed? What still puzzled me is that your mapping is `/*` and your Filter does not set the status 404. So why would Tomcat think your requesting an unmapped (not found) URL?